# How can I calculate the probability of Neutrino hiting in a certain detector?

Tags: probability, neutrinos

I was looking through the DUNE experiment. And it led me to think, If there's way to calculate or do probability where the neutrino might hit in a large chunk of matter in a given neutrino beam rate.

Comment: it is not simple  but that is how the experiment looks for cosmic neutrino interactions, having calculated the neutrino matter crossection.  https://indico.fnal.gov/event/19346/contributions/51548/attachments/32048/39314/Noemi_Rocco_Lepton_nucleus_cross_section_theory.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to ask what you're asking, I.e. WHERE the neutrino hits: everywhere with the same probability. That is because the neutrino mean free path is much, much larger than the size of the detector.

Alternatively, the interaction rate of any beam of particles in any detector is to first order simply equal to particle flux times density of your target times the cross section of your interaction.